# Domain of function when open circles are included in graph

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

how would I write the domain of this function? Would I ignore the part of the graph with the open circles like this?
 $\{x \ \  / \ -4 \leq  x \leq -2 \text{ or } 1 \leq x \leq 4\}$

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine the domain, you need to figure out which values of $x$ have corresponding values of $y$ (that is, for which $x$ is $f(x)$ defined. In this case, clearly $[-4,-2]$ is in the domain, and also $-1$ is not. The point you are probably asking about is $x=1$. At $x=1$, even though there is an open circle at the point $(1,2)$, the function is defined at $x=1$, with $f(1) = 1$. So the interval $(-1,4]$ is in the domain of $f$.

Comment: So anytime there is a portion of the graph with open circles it is not included in the domain, correct? Does that mean that the domain I included in my question is expressed correctly?

Comment: No, that's not right. First of all, $0$ is (for example) in the domain, as is any number $x$ with $-1 < x < 1$. But also $1$ is in the domain: even though there is an open circle above $1$, there is *also* a closed circle. To determine $f(1)$, look at the value of $y$ above $x=1$ in the graph: that is $y=1$. $-1$ is *not* in the domain since there is no point on the graph lying above $x=-1$.

Comment: So the domain is $-4 \le x\le -2$ or $-1 < x \le 4$.

Comment: Ahh thank you for clearing that up, I see exactly what you mean! Thank you for taking the time to help